# Using XMLHttpRequest() in Javascript Problem

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap

I'm implementig access to Webservice using Javascript XMLHttpRequest() and SOAP. I can't make it work.

I can get it using asp:ScriptManager.
The xml SOAP I'm using in javascrito is OK and tested with Postman

Here the Webservice code
    ...c#

```
using Sytem.Web;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class app_ident : System.Web.Services.WebService   
{
    public app_ident()
    {
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetAuth(string ps_no_telefone)
    {
        string vs_url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        if (vs_url.IndexOf("https://") == -1 && vs_url.IndexOf("localhost") == -1) return "{\"return_code\": \"500\", \"msg\": \"SECURITY ERROR - ONLY IN HTTPS\"}";
        return "Autorization Granted to " + ps_no_telefone;
    }
}
...
```

Now the Javascript I'm using

```
...Javascript
<script>
    function CallIdent() {
        var vs_parameter = document.getElementById("parameter").value;
        vs_parameter = '{ "telefone": "' + vs_parameter + '"}';
        var vs_soap = getSoapHeader(vs_parameter);
        GetService("https://sb.cgpsgi.com.br/_webservices/app_ident.asmx", vs_soap);
    }
    function WhenCompleted(pb_result, obj_data) {
        if (pb_result) {
            obj_data = obj_results.substring(1, obj_data.length - 1);
            var as_values = obj_data.split(',');
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = as_values[0] + "<br />" + as_values[1] + "<br />" + as_values[2] + "<br />" + as_values[3];
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "No Response from Web Service";
        }
    }
    function WhenError(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
    }
    function GetService(ps_url, ps_soapXml) {
        var obj_xmlDoc = null;
        try {
            obj_xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Set WhenCompleted for returning results
            var obj_self = this;
            obj_xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = function () {
                obj_self.StateChange(obj_xmlDoc, WhenCompleted);
            };

            // Prepare and Post Webservice Call
            obj_xmlDoc.open("POST", ps_url, true);
            obj_xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            obj_xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            obj_xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", ps_soapXml.length);
            // obj_xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://sb.cgpsgi.com.br/_webservices/app_rv_ident.asmx");
            obj_xmlDoc.send(ps_soapXml);
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (WhenCompleted) {
                WhenCompleted(false, "Error Creating XMLHttpRequest");
            }
        }
        StateChange = function (pobj_xmlDoc, ps_completed) {
            if (pobj_xmlDoc.readyState === 4) {
                var vs_text = "";
                if (pobj_xmlDoc.status === 200) {
                    vs_text = pobj_xmlDoc.responseText;
                }
                // Perform callback with data if callback function signature was provided, 
                if (ps_completed !== null) {
                    ps_completed(pobj_xmlDoc.status === 200, vs_text);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    function getSoapHeader(ps_message) {
        // This SOAP Header is Correct. Tested on PostMan
        // 2019-08-08 - 3st
        var soap = "" +
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
            "<Body>" +
            "<GetAuth xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
            "<ps_no_telefone>" + ps_message + "</ps_no_telefone>" +
            "</GetAuth>" +
            "</Body>" +
            "</Envelope>";
        return soap;
    }
</script>
```

The webservice returns authorization to get access to other services. It returns a json containing return code and a message.

Using asp:ScriptManager it works.
   {"return_code": "0", "msg": "AUTORIZATION GRANTED"}

Using XMLHttpRequest and SOAP it cannot get access to the Webservice.

Comment: Are you running this code in a browser? When you open the devtools (F12 for most browsers) can you see the request and response, is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: I've just found the problem. CORS is blocking access to the webservice using javascript, XMLHttpRequest and SOAP. Interestigly I can get access to it using asp:ScriptManager.

Comment: CORS policies are a browser thing, if you're using a tool that is not a browser (like scriptmanager?) it might not need a CORS policy.